# Function call inside make file ( Linux)

Tags: linux, make

Inside a makefile, I saw the entries below:

```
main entry
    pkt_srv() { }
    pkt_ent() { }
    pku_lib() { }
```

So, is this calling another make file. i.e `pkt_srv.mak` and `pkt_ent.mak` and what is the meaning of `omk` file extension?

Comment: We cannot help, since you don't show your real `Makefile`. The `.mak` & `.omk` are extensions conventional to your project. I saw other projects using `-include foo.mk` directives in their `Makefile`. YMMV. I strongly suggest diving into the [documentation of GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: You could also use `make --trace`  or [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` to understand more what is happening.